# pysvn.ClientError: WC locked with sqlite attempt to write a readonly database during checkout to a same directory in the second time

Tags: python, linux, svn, pysvn

I tried to use a temp directory for repeated checkout and remving, like follow:

```py
client = pysvn.Client()
url = "..."
path = "\tmp\temp_dir"

client.checkout(url, path)   # it's ok here

# clear dir and checkout again
shutil.rmtree(path)
os.makedirs(path) # ok until here

assert not os.listdir(path)
client.checkout(url, path)  # EXCEPTION!
```

with last line excute, it raise an exception **pysvn.ClientError: Working copy '/tmp/temp_dir' locked** with additional errors:**sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database**.

I tried to checkout in terminal with `svn checkou` and it works fine. But even after I remove the files checkouted by command line, I still CANNOT checkout by pysvn in code with same exception.

Some additional information:

- I use python3.4 with pysvn 1.8.0 on linux.
- Using python3.5 with pysvn 1.9.9 on Windows **does not** trigger same problem.

Could anyone help me figure out the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by obtaining a new `pysvn.Client` instance. In the other word, by using following code:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.checkout(url, path)   # it's ok here

# clear dir and checkout again
shutil.rmtree(path)
os.makedirs(path) # ok until here
assert not os.listdir(path)

client = pysvn.Client()     # obtain another instance
client.checkout(url, path)  # ok
```

It seems that there is some information cached in a `pysvn.Client` instance that stopped me from checkout again but I don't know why.